R: Simulating a FIFO (First In First Out) Queue in R
Originally I had posted this question here R: How to Simulate a Queue . I am trying to simulate another such problem:

Suppose there is a factory with 5 employees
Each day, boxes arrive at the factory according to some random date
Employees work on the boxes based on a First In First Out (FIFO) rule : Boxes that have been waiting for longer periods of time are processed before boxes waiting for shorter periods of time
The employees can finish a box based on some other random rate. Once they finish a box, they immediately move to the next box (employees are never idle and never take breaks)
In the situation that there more than two employees are sitting idle since there are no new boxes, the employee that was sitting idle the longest will be assigned in the newest box

Imagine this factory is open for 10 hours each day. I want to simulate the detailed evolution of this factory over 10 days
Here is my logic.
Step 1: Define initial parameters
library(data.table)

lambda_arrival <- 5  # Arrival rate (Poisson)
lambda_service <- 3  # Service rate (Exponential)
hours_per_day <- 10
days <- 10
workers <- 5

results <- vector("list", days * hours_per_day)
completed_boxes <- vector("list", days * hours_per_day)

box_id_counter <- 1

Step 2: Define a Queue Function - this took me the longest time to do. It was really confusing to synchronize the dynamics of the factory (i.e. ensuring that incomplete boxes from the previous hours are worked on chronologically):
simulate_hour <- function(hour, day, queue, workers_status) {
    # Generate arrivals
    arrivals <- rpois(1, lambda_arrival)
    arrival_times <- rep(hour, arrivals)
    arrival_days <- rep(day, arrivals)
    arrival_ids <- seq(box_id_counter, box_id_counter + arrivals - 1)
    box_id_counter <<- box_id_counter + arrivals
    
    # Update queue with new arrivals
    if (arrivals > 0) {
        new_boxes <- data.table(box_id = arrival_ids, arrival_hour = arrival_times, arrival_day = arrival_days, arrival_id = arrival_ids, waiting_time = 0)
        queue <- rbind(queue, new_boxes)
    }
    
    # Process boxes
    completed <- data.table(worker = character(0), box_id = numeric(0), completion_hour = numeric(0), completion_day = numeric(0), arrival_hour = numeric(0), arrival_day = numeric(0))
    for (i in 1:workers) {
        if (nrow(queue) > 0) {
            service_time <- rexp(1, lambda_service)
            queue[1, waiting_time := waiting_time + service_time]
            completed <- rbind(completed, data.table(worker = paste0("worker_", i), box_id = queue[1, box_id], completion_hour = hour, completion_day = day, arrival_hour = queue[1, arrival_hour], arrival_day = queue[1, arrival_day]))
            queue <- queue[-1]
        }
    }
    
    # Update waiting times for remaining boxes
    queue[, waiting_time := waiting_time + 1]
    
    # Store results
    results[[hour + (day - 1) * hours_per_day]] <<- data.table(current_hour = hour, current_day = day, queue)
    completed_boxes[[hour + (day - 1) * hours_per_day]] <<- completed
    
    return(queue)
}

# Simulate 10 days
queue <- data.table(box_id = numeric(0), arrival_hour = numeric(0), arrival_day = numeric(0), arrival_id = numeric(0), waiting_time = numeric(0))
for (day in 1:days) {
    for (hour in 1:hours_per_day) {
        queue <- simulate_hour(hour, day, queue, workers)
    }
}

Step 3: Run the simulation
queue <- data.table(box_id = numeric(0), arrival_hour = numeric(0), arrival_day = numeric(0), arrival_id = numeric(0), waiting_time = numeric(0))
for (day in 1:days) {
    for (hour in 1:hours_per_day) {
        queue <- simulate_hour(hour, day, queue, workers)
    }
}

print(results[[1]])
print(completed_boxes[[1]])

Problem: Although this simulation runs without errors, in this simulation, a worker only finishes one box an hour. How can I make it so that when a worker is finished a box, they start working on the next one?
Thanks!

Don't think anyone is going to do a complete code review of your program since you aren't asking about a specific modular element of it and it's otherwise just unique to your use case with respect to what information you want to save (or not). Additionally, a lot of the detail in your code is a consequence of wanting a specific output structure that you don't detail. Otherwise you don't need to store a lot of intermediate steps.
However, your functions operate per hour but you could easily vectorize a lot of this to simulate the entire time window to make cleaner and faster code. As an example, consider replacing  arrivals<- rpois(1, lambda_arrival) with  arrivals_during_interval <- rpois(hours_per_day*days, lambda_arrival). You could then generate an entire vector of boxes completed and another for not completed boxes during the time period using things like diff(), cumsum() etc.
If you want to see if your code actually accomplishes what you desire, I recommend removing the stochastic element (replace random number generators with constants) and using small numbers for the simulation then checking the output by hand.

@ Socialscientist: thank you for your reply! I am currently working on this - will keep you updated...

If you want a discrete event simulation, try using the package 'simmer'

@ Retired Data Munger: thank you for your reply! I am aware of this package! I just wanted to try and do this by myself  :)
